# missing controller in .net mvc with elmah emailing me...driving me crazy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah.mvc

elmah is emailing me exceptions for missing controllers like so:

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path
>   '/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js' was not found or does
>   not implement IController.

I added some ignore routes to try and let the app know that scripts isn't a controller and to ignore all .js and .css files like so:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("scripts/*");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("*.js|css");
```

It's still emailing me the exception.  at this point I want to just suppress the error because every single time I hit a page on the app, it triggers this email.

any suggestions to cure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the script it is looking for actually exists in the site. I have had problems like this reported in Elmah, and as I remember, it was after a js library had been updated by NuGet, but the references in the views had not.

Hope that helps.

Comment: wow...I feel really sheepish.  That was exactly my problem.  Curse me for copying and pasting into my _layout.cshtml file.  Thanks much.